# Better reflect the suggest edit guideline to what editors approve/reject

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Currently when you suggest an edit a few guidelines are represented. Two of these I however find misleading since even when applying them correctly an edit will still get rejected.

These two are

- clarify meaning without changing it
- correct minor mistakes

**clarify meaning without changing it**

A good example i have come across is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2711641). The validation has nothing to do with anything. What he really wants is to `Get $this->Auth->user('id') in user model cakephp`. This is the title of the question, is listed as the last sentence in the question, all the answers are related to that and why i successfully flagged it as a duplicate to another question that was exactly about that. Anything else just makes it confusing. It's like reading through a whole Bible plus Manuscripts before going to the real question. So that's what i did, i clarified the meaning (`Get $this->Auth->user('id') in user model cakephp`) without changing it by removing the whole thing about validation.

It got there denied probably because what i removed too many characters. But if i remove less characters it's [not good as well](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1936703)

**correct minor mistakes**

From what I experienced by minor mistakes it means only grammar/spelling mistakes and even then it is unsure it will not get rejected because you have to correct not too less and not too many, just somewhere in between. When it comes to code, even the slightest code changes are not allowed. I tried to edit only a crucial part only one character but that got every time rejected. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2285026) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2276484). [There](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1531767) are [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2694157) with similar minor mistakes.

A funny one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455092/cakephp-javascript-confirm-dialog-form-submission-cancel-not-working/5460988#5460988). Everyone with a bit of experience in coding would easily see that this would turn into a loop. I know other people say i would have to downvote it but that means i have to put the right version as another answer which would then be 99% the same as the original. I really don't understand how that is going to be any good. Especially when someone sees an error with my answer and does the same. For this reason I now put those things as comments. Here the guy clearly endorse me to make a suggested edit. Just to test it out i gave it a shot and clearly put in the explanation box `see comments`. But got [Rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2762110) as expected.

For this reason I think it should be better if the guidelines were more clear and not promote things that the reviewer community clearly disapproves anyway.

Comment: the real issue is with reviewers rejecting things they sshouldn't and approving things they shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Editing is hard. The help centre tries to help, but you're never going to get two or three simple sentences that tell you everything you need to know about suggesting edits. Instead you get up to several hundred of your edits reviewed, to teach you what is a good suggested edit and what is not.

The system isn't perfect; some reviewers don't live up to the standards of the site. But it's what we have. And there are a TON of questions and answers here on meta about what constitutes too minor, is it ok to edit code in the question, how can I let reviewers know I am not changing the meaning even though I changed a lot of characters, and so on. If you want to be a better editor, please do read those.

IF what you want is to make the help centre text different, I reject that request. The help centre cannot be comprehensive on this matter so I would prefer it was simple.